# Jquery array.length is shorter than the real array length

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to jquery and a I've got the problem as mentioned in the title.
My controller code looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult getProjectList()
    {
        List<Project> projectList = new List<Project>();

        foreach (IML.ProjectInfo pr in getProjectArray())
        {

            Project x = new Project(pr.Name, pr.ID, pr.OwnerID, pr.CreatedBy, pr.CreatedAt, "", pr.Deleted, pr.Closed);
            projectList.Add(x);
        }

        return Json(projectList.ToArray());

    }
```

When I check the projectList under debugger mode it has 6 elements.
In my webpage I have the following ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("getProjectList")',
        type: "POST",
        //enumerowanie projektów
        success: function (data) {                
            projekty = data;

            var wyswietl ="<table><tbody>";
            var tabelka = "";
            var wybranyProjekt;

            alert($.data.length);//this alert tells me that data.length is 3
            for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)//even if $.data.length is 3 the data[i].Name holds values for 6 elements
            {                   
                tabelka += "<tr class=\"enumeracjaProj\" id=\"" + i
                    + "\"><td class=\"projekty\" id=\"" + i + "\"> " + data[i].Name + " </td></tr>"
            }

            wyswietl += tabelka;
            wyswietl += "</tbody></table>";               
            $('#projekty_div').append(wyswietl);
```

})

Even if I Post an array of 6 elements ajax result tell me that its length is 3. If I go over it in loop which was 6 iterations hard-coded I get properly displayed name.

Comment: What is the data type you expect? i mean json or text? First specify data type in ajax call. Can you post the value for JSON.stringify(data)? (in your success function)

Comment: Ive specify the type of data now ajax call looks like this:
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("getProjectList")',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json", 
        //enumerowanie projektów
        success: function (data) {...
but there is no change.

Comment: Yes let us know value of this JSON.stringify(data)? simply add alert inside the success function like alert(JSON.stringify(data));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small correction, You should change your `alert($.data.length);` to `alert(data.length);`

`$.data` is jQuery function and your `data` is response result

Comment: Can you explain my what is length in $.data.length?